# Default spring form field values are cleared after fail validation

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to springMVC and came across this issue that I don't understand. I have a JSP with a form in which some fields get prepopulated in my get method with some
values I get from the database. when I submit my form through the POST method and the required fields are not filled then I call my GET method to show the form again with
error messages on the top of the page. Everything works good and my fields that need to be prepopulated gets populated correctly.

The issue that we came across in testing is that when we delete the prepopulated fields and submit again, my POST method calls my GET method to redisplay the page with error
messages and the error messages appear fine on the screen but my fields that suppose to be prepopulated with some values are not getting repopulated again even 
though I am calling the database and populating my form with the model.put() method in my GET method everytime.

It seems like spring does not populate any field on the JSP if there are errors. Is that right?

This is a simplyfied version of my controller, but it will explain what I'm trying to do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = myPageURL, method = GET)
public String displayPage(@ModelAttribute("someForm") SomeForm someForm,
                          BindingResult bindingResult,
                          ModelMap model) {

    //call the database and get some values
    someform.setSomefield1("someValue1");
    someform.setSomefield2("someValue2");
    model.put("someform", someForm)

        return VIEW;
}

@RequestMapping(value = myPageURL, method = POST)
public String submitform(@ModelAttribute("someForm") SomeForm someForm,
                                     BindingResult bindingResult,
                                     ModelMap model) {
validate(someForm, bindingResult);
    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        //Display some page
    }

    return displayPage(someForm, bindingResult, model);

}
```

This is a section of the JSP:

```
<form:form action=myPageURL method="POST" modelAttribute="someForm">
<form:hidden path="cid"/>
  <td>
    <form:input path="someField1" size="10" maxlength="20" cssErrorClass="fieldError      
       error-text-first-name-label"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form:input path="someField2" size="10" maxlength="20" cssErrorClass="fieldError 
     error-text-last-name-label"/>
 </td>
 <td>
   <form:input path="someField3" size="10" maxlength="20" cssErrorClass="fieldError 
    error-text-last-name-label"/>
 </td>

</form:form>
```

Thanks